# Custom C module includes

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, cpython

I'm trying to build a Python module with C and stuck on an issue:

When I include additional header file( `test.h`), module compile with no warnings, but later on `import` this module, Python complains about the undefined symbol `maketest`.

My module structure looks like this (the module is named `spam`):

```
spam\
    ├spammodule.c
    |setup.py
    ├─src\
         |── test.c
         |── test.h
```

Content of `spammodule.c`:

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include "test.h"

static PyObject * SpamError;

static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    maketest(); // <---- calling function from additional file

    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;

    sts = system(command);
    if ( sts < 0 ) {
        PyErr_SetString(SpamError, "System command failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyLong_FromLong(sts);
}

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    PyObject *m;
    static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
        {"system", spam_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command."},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
    };
    m = Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
    if ( m == NULL )
        return;

    SpamError = PyErr_NewException("spam.error", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(SpamError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "error", SpamError);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    initspam();
}
```

Contents of `setupy.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup,Extension

spam_module = Extension('spam',
        sources = ['spammodule.c'],
        include_dirs=['src/'],)

setup ( name = 'Spam',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'Sample module.',
    ext_modules = [ spam_module ])
```

Contents of `src/test.h`:

```c
void maketest(void);
```

Contents of `src/test.c`:

```c
#include "test.h"

void maketest() {
    printf("test passed");
}
```

I compile everything with `python setup.py build`, after running Python prompt I try to import my module and get the error:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./spam.so: undefined symbol: maketest
```

Does someone have a clue what's going on?

Comment: You're *absolutely nowhere* linking in the object file of `src/test.c` into the `.so`. Add `src/test.c` to the sources list.

Comment: You're right, i thought that including `src/*` files is enough, but no, as You said additional files should be listed in sources tuple, thanks. I added answer to my post

Comment: no, you should *post* your answer as an *answer*. Then *accept it*!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys thanks *Antii* for clue as You said problem was that test.c should be included in sources tuple
so i modified setup.py and everything works fine
now it look`s like this:

```
from setuptools import setup,Extension

spam_module = Extension('spam',
        sources = ['spammodule.c','src/test.c'],
        include_dirs=['src/'])

setup ( name = 'Spam',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'Sample module.',
    ext_modules = [ spam_module ])
```